# Why when i open a new JFrame my components changes format?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

When i start the Jframe "VentanaPrincipal" this one looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ESSw.png]

but when I open the Jframe from another Jframe, it changes the format of the components:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFZVU.png]

My code is:

```
 VentanaPrincipal vp = new VentanaPrincipal();
 vp.setVisible(true);
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The Look and Feel (LAF) is changing.

Swing components use the LAF at the time the component is created.

It would seem that one frame uses a different LAF so the second frame inherits that LAF when it is created.

Fix your code to use the same LAF.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Modifying the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) for more information.